# Try Google App Engine Now - creating a first app on google cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

When I am creating my first app following the link

https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine

using Python project appengine-try-python-flask

When I am doing deploy the project, it is asking email and password, in search it is showing we need to register the app with google API, before deploying it.

Then when I am going to

https://console.developers.google.com/project

and clicking on the project name, it is going to project dashboard, then I am clicking on Enable an API,

then i clicked on Google Maps Engine API, for on, then APIs are activated.

but still I am not getting where to get the password it is asking when I am doing

appcfg.py update appengine-try-python-flask

where to get this required password for deploying the app. This is the sample Hello World app, and I am trying to deploy it for the first time. I have done the first five steps given in the above mentioned first link on console developers start appengine

I am stuck on the sixth step deploy the project

Comment: i tried using gmail password many times, but it is not working, i feel problem is it is not able to identify the project for which it is asking email and password. i feel some changes are to be made to app.yaml file or main.py file.

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked for your email and password on Google. Just use the same email and password you use to log in on any Google Service (Google+, Gmail, etc)

Comment: using gmail password is not working (i tried it many times). i feel problem is that it is not able to identify the corresponding project for which it is asking email and password, i feel some changes are to be made in app.yaml file or main.py file.

Comment: i found out - we need a application specific password.

Comment: Wow, interesting. It is expected though, but difficult to think about at first. Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

i found out that if the google account is using 2-step verification process, then we need an application specific password generated from security settings of the account.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en